# Flag Edit to be rolled back

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, flags

In [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38226234/6408573), a user decided to edit the question's code to provide a solution to the problem.  I feel like this is pretty clearly the wrong way to answer a question, so I posted a comment informing the user and re-editted the question to remove the offending changes.

For the future, is there any way (or should a way be added) to flag an *approved* edit like this (that so clearly should not have been accepted) for re-review/rollback?  Obviously, editting the question again to remove the offending issues accomplishes the same task, but that feels like a round about way of solving the problem.

Comment: If you don't have edit privileges it may be better just to custom moderator flag the question or raise it here so someone with edit privileges can roll back the edit.

Comment: There already is a way: flag -> in need of moderator intervention. Clearly the usual review process has not worked correctly in this case, so some exception handling is needed. You could ask in Meta or chat to get it rolled back, but only the mods have the tools to look into whether other actions (review bans, etc.) are needed.

Comment: @RobertLongson exactly my thought.  I guess the obvious answer is to flag the question itself, but I was curious as to why there isn't (and whether there should be) a way to specifically flag _the edit_ for review, rather than the entire question

Comment: In the mean time, I will flag it for moderator attention

Comment: Interesting... anyway... it's been handled. Thanks.

Comment: I hope the reviewers were temporarily banned from reviewing. Accepting that edit is just ... disappointing.

Comment: @Tom looking at the reviews, one reviewer rejected it and specifically made the same point I've made here.  Good on him, but I agree that those others should at the very least be notified to be more cautious in approving future edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users above 2.000 reputation or the post owner can roll back any edit on any non-locked post by clicking a button in the revision history. Failing 2.000 reputation, you can flag the question for moderator attention (Click the "flag" link and select "in need of moderator attention" and explain the issue).

Or, other then that, you can do what you just did, and raise the issue on meta. As a consequence of this thread, a moderator has reverted the edit.

You're right by the way, edits to code other then indentation fixing or inlining are generally discouraged, and editing an answer into a question is also discouraged.

Comment: I partially raised this question to suggest the possibility of specifically flagging an edit, but I guess that may be a bit too niche to deserve its own flag.  For the future, I'll be sure to flag for moderator attention

Comment: @RGA That already exists, its called a moderator flag. When you have issue with an edit, you flag the post the edit was on. I don't think we need to be able to flag edits specifically :p